# SliverAppBar only push up after some scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-appbar

I have a SliverAppBar (floating: true, pinned: false).

I want to achieve that the user has to scroll 200 pixels (or some other amount) before the SliverAppBar starts to compress/slide-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `pinned` value is not supposed to be changed. If you try to change it after scrolling 200 pixels, the `SliverAppBar` would shrink suddenly.

You can check this out by running the code below:

```dart
class Buster extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BusterState createState() => _BusterState();
}

class _BusterState extends State<Buster> {
  ScrollController controller;
  bool isAppBarPinned;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(onScroll);
    isAppBarPinned = true;
  }

  void onScroll() {
    if (controller.position.pixels > 200) {
      if (isAppBarPinned) {
        setState(() => isAppBarPinned = false);
      }
    } else {
      if (!isAppBarPinned) {
        setState(() => isAppBarPinned = true);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: controller,
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Buster'),
            floating: true,
            pinned: isAppBarPinned,
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 150,
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
                  .map((int index) => Center(child: Text('Item #$index')))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I think the best option you got here is using a regular `AppBar` and [animate it manually](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations) with a [`Transform`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html).

Comment: What I think could work is to insert a Sliver before the SliverAppBar exactly at the moment you set pinned to true and let it consume the scroll height and remove that piece from the list.

Comment: The other option might be to write a custom RenderSliver that dynamically consumes some scrolling space.